# Naming a second additional column referencing another table column?

Tags: naming-convention

I'm working with a table in database that references to a column in another table. 
Such as:

```
Product Table
------------
Id
Description
Currencies_Code

Currencies
------------
Id
Code
Description
```

We have the convention:

"Foreign key fields should be a combination of the name of the referenced table and the name of the referenced fields."

MyColumn: ExternalTableName_ColumnName

Until there, everything is fine. Now, a second column should be added referencing to Currencies table "Code" column for a second scenario where another currency should be used.

My initial idea was using these columns:

Currencies_Code_Internal

Currencies_Code_External

However, the suffix Internal/External breaks the convention.

Which way of naming would be the most appropiate in this case to change the convention?

Comment: it's *your* convention; how can we be expected to make that judgment call for *you*?

Comment: in fact, for what Thomas explains below, this violation of convention  is caused by a design problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider that the breaking of the convention is actually indicative of an error or inefficiency in the design:

For example,

I would have a lookup table for this instead of two occurences of the same foreign key field in a table.

```
Product Table
------------
Id
Description

Product_Currencies Table
------------
Product_Id
Currencies_Id
Condition_Id

Condition Table
-----------------------
Id
Description

Currencies
------------
Id
Code
Description
```

In effect, the Product_Currencies table formalizes the relationship : 
Given *this condition*, use *this currency* for *this product*.

The condition table might contain values like:

```
Condition
ID     Description
----------------
1      Internal 
2      External
```

The naming convention being broken may be a symptom of a problematic design- many conventions are partially intended to cause issues when violated.

Having two `Currencies_Code` in one table implies conditional use, which may imply another relation is necessary to describe it.

**If you must have an answer to the original question:**

It's totally and entirely dependent on who enforces and/or codifies your standard.

Comment: "It's totally and entirely dependent on who enforces and/or codifies your standard" -> that bit.

Comment: thank you very much @Thomas, what you explain there is very useful and you give the reasons why wrong design is involved here. It clarifies the scenario a lot.